# my baked texture doent match the real time texture

Tags: uv, node-editor, shaders, image, texture-baking

i made a 3d model of a gun and now i want to involve it in an animation and for that i want to bake the texture , so i tried to do a combined bake for a part of my gun

**Here's the picture before bake**

[image]

**the bake after applying baked texture**

[image]

it is clearly visible that the baked texture has something off that is making the gun look darker , i have directly applied the image texture as the surface and applying it as base color and emission color doesn't work.**How should i solve this problem**

Comment: I got it myself , i plugged the baked texture into the emission of the principled shader to solve the problem instead of emission node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it myself , i plugged the baked texture into the emission of the principled shader to solve the problem instead of emission node